# Efficient way to validate a Connect Four game

Tags: performance, algorithm

I'm scanning a Connect Four game with opencv into a data structure similar to [this one (by John Tromp)](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~tromp/c4/Connect4.java). Basically it uses a 7 x 7 [bitboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitboard) (with only zeros in the top row) for each player to be able to quickly check for a winner using mostly bitshift operators and no loops.

There are many good Algorithms out there to check for a winner but I couldn't find one to check if the board itself represents a valid position.

These are the criteria for a valid position as decribed by [Victor Allis in his Masters thesis](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~fernau/DSL0607/Masterthesis-Viergewinnt.pdf):

1. "If the total number of occupied squares in a given position is odd, the number of white men is one more than the number of black men. If the total of occupied squares is even, these numbers are equal."
2. "Furthermore, if a column contains an empty square, all squares higher than this square are also empty."
3. "If a position contains four connected men, the position concludes a game. Since the last move ended the game, at least one of the four squares in the connected group must be the highest filled square in its column. If this is not the case, or both players have connected four men, the position is illegal."
4. "If one player has more than one connected group this position can only be legal if these groups share a square which contains the last man played."

In addition, there are positions that are impossible to get to while strictly applying all rules. Here's a simple example:

```
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . x . . .
. . . o . . .  (where x plays first)
```

Given the data structure mentioned above, is there any way to check all these conditions (especially 3 and 4) without expensive loops or recursive calls?

Comment: I think you don't need to worry about this, because even very ineffective option would take milisecond on slow CPU.

Comment: What would be a lot harder to determine is whether it would have been possible to actually ever get into this state. So even if condition 1 to 4 is met it could still be illegal in the sense that it would have been impossible to get there if you need to take turns strictly alternating.

Comment: @Sebastian I was actually just editing this condition in ;)

Comment: @ST3 You're probably right for rules 1 to 4, especially in my case the bottleneck is the opencv algorithm, not the validation.